# Nokia Here.com REST API

Tags: rest

I'm new to Rest.

[image]

Above is the geocode request from here.com RestApi.

Is there any link or example to demonstrate this request?
I have no idea to start it. 
Thank you very much~

Comment: You could take the entire above into a browser(meaning click this [link](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=7&housenumber=425&street=W+Randolph&city=Chicago) and make the request). Other than that there are many tutorials on consuming REST services you should probably check one out in the language of your choice.

Comment: OH! Your link 'link' is working!

Comment: Find tutorial in Google please

Comment: I have searching thru the Google lar...

Comment: Thanksss scappedcola. I copy directly the link, it will include wrong characters, making the link not workable.